# error Input string was not in a correct format in the first line int a

Tags: c#

```
  private void txtrate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtqty.Text);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtrate.Text);
            int c = a * b;
            txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(c);




             //txttotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtqty.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtrate.Text)).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It means that txtqty.Text is not a number.

Comment: That is just an error message and some code. You forgot to write a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this error occurs of txtqty.Text (or txtrate.Text for variable b) does not contain a valid number. So the user entered letters or other characters instead of 0 till 9.

You could try to validate your input first with `TryParse`:

```
private void txtrate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtqty.Text); 
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtrate.Text); 
    if (Int32.TryParse(txtqty.Text, out a) && (Int32.TryParse(txtrate.Text, out b)
    {
        int c = a * b; 
        txttotal.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is due to the value not contained only numbers, to avoid this situation, please setup the type of data you are trying to collect with the text fields, you can setup [refer this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220519/Numbers-or-Characters-only-Textbox-Validation-in-C) for a detailed walk through on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest `TryParse`too :

```
private void txtrate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtqty.Text, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         //Converting is Ok, proceed        
      }
      else
      {
         //Convertign fail
         txtqty.Focus();
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter only number for this field");
         return;
      }
   }
```

I would suggest making this for each textbox with setting the focus to the textbox with incorrect input and providing an useful message for the user. In my opinion this is a suitable and user-friendly way.